# Array Math on n dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I've lost all my hair on this.  I've got a 3 dimensional array.

Initialized as Array.new(rows) { Array.new(columns) { Array.new(CHANNELS, 0) } }

Everything seems to work, but when i try to add columns of padding, i can't figure out how the 2nd dimension gets whacked.

i've done this about 5 different ways and keep coming up with the wrong size for the second dimension.  The first part works okay, i initialize an array stack_edge to be an array of 1xn pixels and push/unsift it to the beginning and end of image_data.  which then becomes and array 0...pads...original height...original_height_2*pads) rows.

But then i try and push & unshift pixexls onto the columns of each row and get an array that thinks it's wider than it is.  It reports a width of 110 pixels wider than the original.  I can't figure out where the other 100 pixels come from.  They're not there, never notice before since i calculate the with instead of interrogating for it.  (old_width+2*pad_s) worked and all the data appears to be in place, but width= @image_data[row].size, whacks out with the 110 pixel size.  I'm guessing it's because the pixel i'm pushing on is a 10x1 array, and i put 5 in the front and 5 in the back, so 110 by some strange math.  Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
  (0...pad_s).each {
    @image_data.unshift(stack_edge)
    @image_data.push(stack_edge)
  }
  self.rows=@image_data.size
  edge=Array.new(image_data[0][0].size)

  a='whats up'
  (0...@image_data.size).each { |i|
      (0...pad_s).each{
        @image_data[i].unshift(edge)
        @image_data[i].push([edge)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please make your question more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing/unshifting *the same* `stack_edge` array 5 times on the front and 5 times on the back of `@image_data`. So when you run over `@image_data` and push/unshift 10 "edges" onto each array in `@image_data`, those 10 edges are added to `stack_edge` *10 times*. Because the same `stack_edge` appears in 10 different positions in `@image_data`. Get it?

What you need is:

```
@image_data.unshift(stack_edge.dup)
@image_data.push(stack_edge.dup)
```

This is what is called an "aliasing bug". They tend to be a problem in OO languages.

Comment: Those aliaising bugs drive me nuts.  yes i get it.  I have the hardest time getting a copy of an array instead of a pointer to it:)